# Выборка данных регулярным выражением в php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Всем привет, немного не могу разобраться с регулярными выражениями.
Имеется строка вида:

> FORMTEXT Рыбаков(фамилия)(группа крови)(дата определения) FORMTEXT
>   Владимир FORMTEXT Владиславович(имя, отчество)(резус)(подпись врача)
>   FORMTEXT

Как можно посредством регулярных выражений через php вытащить отсюда фамилию, имя и отчество? Соответственно должно получится: Рыбаков Владимир Владиславович.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Организовать поиск по ключевому слову `FORMTEXT`, за которым следует один пробел `\s` - после пробела, собственно искомое слово `\w+`, а за этим словом альтернативный выбор: или скобка `(`, или пробел с ключевым словом `\sFORMTEXT`. Чтобы ключевые слова с пробелами **не** попадали в результат *выборки*, можно заключить их в конструкции назад и вперёд смотрящих проверок: `(?<=FORMTEXT\s)` и `(?=\(|\sFORMTEXT)` соответственно. Целиком шаблон примет вид: `(?<=FORMTEXT\s)\w+(?=\(|\sFORMTEXT)`, а вместе с php всё будет выглядеть так:

```
$str = 'FORMTEXT Рыбаков(фамилия)(группа крови)(дата определения) FORMTEXT Владимир FORMTEXT Владиславович(имя, отчество)(резус)(подпись врача) FORMTEXT';

$patt = '~(?<=FORMTEXT\s)\w+(?=\(|\sFORMTEXT)~u';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);
$result = $arr[0] ?? false;

echo join(' ', $result);
```

Результат:

```
Рыбаков Владимир Владиславович
```

Comment: @Bek1zo я добавил в ответ приведение массива к строке.